# Voting on an Answer to a Closed Question

Tags: discussion

There was a question that was closed as an exact duplicate back in Jan 12, 2012 : [What is the right time to use an ENUM versus a normalized types table in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/what-is-the-right-time-to-use-an-enum-versus-a-normalized-types-table-in-mysql)

[My answer to this Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10603/877) was just upvoted at 2012-06-18 22:10:47 UTC.

Am I allowed to receive upvotes to my answer when it is part of a Closed Question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There's nothing that prohibits submitted answers from getting upvotes, unless they are locked (I think that stops upvotes), deleted, or CW. The deleted part should be self-explanatory.

Closing as a dupe (or for whatever other reason) still allows your answer to be marked as accepted, upvoted, and edited.